# Are No Free Lunch theorem and Universal Approximation theorem contradictory in the context of neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, comparison, computational-learning-theory, no-free-lunch-theorems, universal-approximation-theorems

To my understanding NFL states that, we cannot have an hypothesis (let's assume it is an approximator like NN in this case) class that can't achieve certain accuracy parameters $\leq \epsilon$ with probability greater than a certain $p$ given the number of points from which we can sample is upper bounded to $m$.

Whereas, the UAC states that an approximator like a NN given enough hidden units can approximate any function (to my knowledge the function must be bounded).

The point where these 2 clashes (as per my knowledge) is that if we increase the paramters in a NN, the UAC will start to hold good, but the VC dimension will increase (or hypothesis class becomes richer) and for the same $m$ our $\epsilon$ increases or $p$ decreases (not sure which one is affected).

So what are the gaps in my knowledge here? How do we make these 2 consistent with each other?